# Как сделать примерно такое условие in ('AUDI' and 'FIAT')

Tags: sql

Всем привет! Уважаемые, помогите составить вот такое условие **in ('AUDI' and 'FIAT')**. Я прекрасно понимаю, что синтаксически так сделать нельзя, но может кто знает как можно сконструировать такое условие. Т.е. по сути я хочу сделать так, чтобы в условии IN выбирались только эти два значения **'AUDI'** и **'FIAT'**

**Поправка. Вот, что мне нужно:**

Таблица со значениями:

```
ID_USER |  VALUE 
---------------- 
   1    |  AUDI   
   2    |  FIAT    
   2    |  AUDI   
   3    |  FIAT
```

надо что бы условие вывело 2 пользователя
у которого и то и то значение есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос

```
SELECT `car`.`ID_USER` 
FROM `car` , (
SELECT `ID_USER` 
FROM `car` 
WHERE `VALUE` = 'AUDI'
) AS t1
WHERE `car`.`VALUE` = 'FIAT'
AND t1.ID_USER = `car`.`ID_USER`
```

еще один

```
SELECT `car`.`ID_USER`
FROM `car` 
WHERE `car`.`VALUE`='FIAT'
and `car`.`ID_USER` in (SELECT `ID_USER` FROM `car` WHERE `VALUE`='AUDI')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select ID_USER from table where VALUE in ('AUDI', 'FIAT')
group by ID_USER 
having count(*) = 2;
```

А если один пользователь с одной маркой может встречаться несколько раз, то так:

```
select ID_USER from table where VALUE in ('AUDI', 'FIAT')
    group by ID_USER 
    having count(distinct VALUE) = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from table where car in ('AUDI', 'FIAT');
```

or

```
select * from table where car='AUDI' or car='FIAT';
```

Comment: мне надо чтобы в выборку попали сразу два значения из условия т.е. если поле не соответствует условию AUDI и FIAT тогда это поле не попадает в выборку... вроде понятно должно быть... мот чего не понятно объясняю

Answer (score 2):

Вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136462#136560) ответ подойдет.

Но предложу еще свой вариант:

```
select ID_USER
  from table t
 where exists (select *
                 from table t1
                where t1.ID_USER = t.ID_User
                  and Value = 'AUDI')
   and exists (select *
                 from table t1
                where t1.ID_USER = t.ID_User
                  and Value = 'FIAT')
```

Comment: Во! Я бы тоже так написал!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from `table` where `car` like('%AUDI%') and `car` like('%FIAT%');
```

Оно посмотрит, чтобы поле содержало оба этих слова. 
Если слова всего два, можно заменить на

```
select * from `table` where `car` = ('AUDI,FIAT') OR `car`=('FIAT,AUDI');
```

UPD. [третья нормальная форма](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Третья_нормальная_форма) вполне способна помочь справиться с данной задачей.
Для этого надо создать таблицу с марками, один раз все проиндексировать, а потом делать запрос на соответствие. Можно через ваш любимый IN. :)

Comment: хорошо! Но LIKE очень долго исполняется.

Comment: Если долго, используйте [третью нормальную форму][1]: она избавит от необходимости парсить поле.

  [1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Третья_нормальная_форма