# SQL запрос

Tags: запрос, sql

Есть таблица вида

```
> Id | gId | cId | pId
> 1  |  0  | 10  | 1
> 2  |  2  |  0  | 1
> 3  |  3  |  0  | 1
> 4  |  4  |  0  | 2
> 5  |  0  | 11  | 2  
> 6  |  4  |  0  | 2
```

Каким запросом из неё можно получить значение pId если заданы gId и cId,
например, gId: 2 или 3 или 4 или 5 или 6, а cId 10, на выходе нужно получить pId 1,
или gId: 2 или 3 или 4 или 5 или 6, а cId 11, на выходе нужно получить pId 2

Comment: условие написано верно?  

>> получить значение pId если заданы gId __И__ cId  
>> и  
>> первый не вернет ничего, потому что нет записей одновременно содержащих cId и gId  

Идем дальше. 

>> gId: 2 или 3 или 4 или 5 или 6, а cId 10, на выходе нужно получить pId 1

Если нет записей одновременно содержащих cId и gId, то получается белиберда.

Comment: ничего не понятно. если pId определяется cId'ом, то зачем условие на gId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие то:

```
select pId
from table t
join (select gId from table where gId in (2,3,4,5)) as t1 on t.gId = t1.gId
join (select cId from table where cId = 11) as t2 on t.cId = t2.cId
```

Comment: да тут можно и без подзапросов. Автор сказал, что "нет записей одновременно содержащих cId и gId", поэтому можно два элементарных условия - либо одно, либо другое.

Comment: Запрос ничего не вернул.
В запрос поступают данные gId: 2 или 3 или 4 или 5 или 6, а cId 10 в итоге нужно получить pId: 1 (это первые 3 столбца).

Comment: Вот теперь вернет pId = 1

    select pid from test where gId in (2,3,4,5,6)
    intersect
    select pid from test where cId = 10

Ну а дальше дело техники )

Comment: Странно, выдаёт ошибку #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'intersect SELECT

Comment: Ну как бы в метках к вопросу не было указано что нужно именно MySQL, поэтому и написал на том что ближе мне))) но теперь предлагаю такой вариант:

    select distinct pId from test
    where gId in (2,3,4,5,6) and  pId in
    (select pId from test where cId = 10)

Comment: Задача решается c применением подзапроса:
SELECT pId FROM tbl WHERE pId IN (SELECT pId FROM tbl WHERE cId='10') AND gId IN (2,3,4,5,6). Ну поскольку @null оказался ближе всех к ответу и натолкнул на правильный, плюсую :)

Comment: Так я вроде тоже самое и написал в своем предыдущем комментарии)

Comment: Очевидно, мы почти одновременно отправили комменты (поскольку когда я писал свой ваш я еще не видел), но то что ответы совпали оно и к лучшему :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pId FROM table WHERE cId='11' AND gId IN (2,3,4,5,6)
или
SELECT pId FROM table WHERE cId='11' OR gId IN (2,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: Оба запроса не правильные, первый не вернет ничего, потому что нет записей одновременно содержащих cId и gId, второй вернет вообще все записи...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pId FROM table WHERE (cId = '11' and gId = '0') or (cId = '0' and gId IN (2,3,4,5,6)
```

разумеется, если я правильно понял условие и сопоставил это знание с ответами и комментами...

Comment: Не правильный запрос, он полностью аналогичен 2 запросу из ответа выше. Нужно выбрать pId из таблицы где cId=11 и gId IN (2,3,4,5,6), но поскольку целых пар нет, возникает сложность с выборкой.

Comment: вообще-то он не_полностью аналогичен_. Первое условие выполняется, если gId пустое, а второе условие выполняется, если cId пустое. В ответе @slowpokewarrior этого нет.  


PS. вы же зоркий все-таки - должны были заметить  
PPS. и вообще нужно вопрос грамотно ставить. тогда не будет неразберихи в ответах.

Comment: Вопрос поставлен максимально понятно, вы если не знаете ответ, то уж хоть чушь не пишите, а если чего то не понимаете то спросите прежде чем написать чушь.

Comment: @Зоркий, не надо агриться и строить из себя ньюфага. Вопрос был не понятен не мне одному. Люди смогли в нем разобраться только спустя некоторое время, что как бэ говорит...  
PS. Ваш быдлокомент даже дислайкнуть умудрулись

Answer (score 1):

Да ладно? Ответ, помеченный правильным не вернет то, что нужно задающему.

Был подобный вопрос, и там я давал свой ответ, его легко переделать для этого вопроса:
[Как сделать примерно такое условие in ('AUDI' and 'FIAT')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136462/sql-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-in-audi-and-fiat?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=136595#136595)